# Can Python's MiniMock create mock of functions defined in the same file?

Tags: python, mocking

I'm using the Python [MiniMock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MiniMock) library for unit testing. I'd like to mock out a function defined in the same Python file as my doctest. Can MiniMock handle that? The naive approach fails:

```
def foo():
    raise ValueError, "Don't call me during testing!"

def bar():
    """
    Returns twice the value of foo()

    >>> from minimock import mock
    >>> mock('foo',returns=5)
    >>> bar()
    Called foo()
    10

    """
    return foo() * 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Here's what happens if I try to run this code:

```
**********************************************************************
File "test.py", line 9, in __main__.bar
Failed example:
    bar()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/doctest.py", line 1212, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest __main__.bar[2]>", line 1, in <module>
        bar()
      File "test.py", line 13, in bar
        return foo() * 2
      File "test.py", line 2, in foo
        raise ValueError, "Don't call me!"
    ValueError: Don't call me!
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   3 in __main__.bar
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

**Edit:** As per the answers below, this has been identified as a bug, and has been [fixed in MiniMock](http://bitbucket.org/jab/minimock/changeset/bb9528bb454d/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just replied on the mailing list with a MiniMock patch that fixes this.

Until that's applied, instead of the following two lines in itsadok's snippet:

```
>>> mock('foo',returns=5)
>>> bar.func_globals['foo'] = foo
```

you could also use

```
>>> mock('foo', nsdicts=(bar.func_globals,), returns=5)
```

Comment: I've applied the patch to tip (see http://bitbucket.org/jab/minimock/changeset/bb9528bb454d/).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
def foo():
    raise ValueError, "Don't call me during testing!"

def bar():
    """
    Returns twice the value of foo()

    >>> from minimock import mock
    >>> mock('foo',returns=5)
    >>> bar.func_globals['foo'] = foo
    >>> bar()
    Called foo()
    10

    """
    return foo() * 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

It seems that the foo in bar is already bound to the original function by the time the mocking takes place.

This happens because when running the doctests, the doctest module [runs in the context of a *copy* of the module's global name space](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#what-s-the-execution-context), but `bar`'s globals remain their original self. So the `mock` function changes the `foo` that is in the copied namespace, but `bar` is still looking at the original.

I don't know if there's a better way to do this.

**EDIT 2**: I take it back. MiniMock was specifically designed to be used in doctests. I suspect you found a bug.

<strike>**EDIT**: I guess the recommended way to do this is to set up the mocking before starting the tests, like so:</strike>

```
def foo():
    raise ValueError, "Don't call me during testing!"

def bar():
    """
    Returns twice the value of foo()

    >>> bar()
    10

    """
    return foo() * 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from minimock import mock
    mock('foo',returns=5)
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

This way the "Called foo()" message is also not in the doctest.

Comment: This issue has been brought up in the MiniMock mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/minimock-dev/browse_thread/thread/f8a583bc862f279?hl=en